# MvxSpinner selecteditem not updated on itemssource change

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am building a form that involves adding items from a list, but the list that is being shown to the user depends on the selection from another list. To do this I have two MvxSpinners each with a bound ItemsSource and SelectedItem.

```
<MvxSpinner
   android:layout_width="300dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource item_source_one; SelectedItem selected_item_one;"/>
<MvxSpinner
   android:layout_width="300dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource item_source_two; SelectedItem selected_item_two;"/>
```

When `selected_item_one` changes `item_source_two` changes to a new list. All of this works, except when `item_source_two` is changed `selected_item_two` remains the same as it was before the change. I would like for the `selected_item_two` to match what is visually shown when `item_source_two` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner binding isn't perfect in MvvmCross - in particular, the `SelectedItem` change must be sent after the `ItemsSource` change.

To work around this, you could signal a fake `SelectedItem` change **after** the `ItemsSource` - e.g. something like:

```
 RaisePropertyChanged(() => item_source_two);
 RaisePropertyChanged(() => selected_item_two);
```

If you wanted to fix this more fully, you could also consider overriding MvxSpinner - sadly you can't easily inherit because we missed virtual, but you do something like:

```
public class MySpinner : MvxSpinner
{
    public MySpinner(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return base.ItemsSource; }
        set 
        { 
            // TODO - work out what the current selection and store it in a local variable
            base.ItemsSource = value; 
            // TODO - reset the current selection here from the local variable
        }
    }
}
```

inheriting from   https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxSpinner.cs

Answer (score 0):

i had to do like this ...

```
public class MySpinner : MvxSpinner
{
   public MySpinner(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context,attrs)
{
}

[MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return base.ItemsSource; }
    set 
    { 
       base.ItemsSource = null;            
       base.ItemsSource = value;     
    }
}
}
```

after that the collection was updated as you type ! :)